# Equations with Array Bidimenensional in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have an array with 310 lines and 120 columns.

I get the data that will populate this array from serial port at intervals of 10 seconds.

How to send this data to the first row of the array and on the next iteration to the line down and it continuously until the operation is complete?

Once completed, take the maximum, minimum and average of the array. And finally, the average,  maximum and minimum of a selection of cells in the Array.

This is possible with array in C#?

```
([7,31]-xxxxx.MIN([$28$5:$45$95])/(xxxxx.MAX[$28$5:$46$95]-xxxxx.MIN[$28$5:$45$95])
```

Comment: The code sample looks like Excel, not C#.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? I suspect a simple foreach loop should suffice...

Comment: Why not just have a List of arrays?

Comment: When sending ID0# command: (0# = 01 or 02 or 03 or 04 or 05 or 06)
receive a string like this  0#,22008,21930,00000, n / a, n / a ! 
But only use the 0#,22008,21930,00000.
Then the string is divided with substring() and the fragments go to variables.
As should be the method which automates sending commands every 10 seconds, receive the strings, splits with substring() and stores them in variables and populates the array?
The code is only a sample to complete my question.
Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be a 2D array? Could it be a List of classes where the class represents one row?

Comment: Do you have any code? If so could you post it so we can see where you are headed?

Comment: As this project has as its data source 6 laser particles counters with high accuracy. 
2 µ,7µ and 10µ. 
After receive string from the serial port, we will treat. 
These data will go to the initial cells of the row (X axis) of the ARRAY. 
This is the first part. 
Each time we receive the data, we will make several equations. 
The results will go to the following cells in the same row of the ARRAY.

Comment: For example with the 6 devices and 4 channels each, remembering that the first channel is the ID and more 3 read channels, we have 24 columns, however, with the equations I'll need more than 64 columns for equations, adding we have 90 columns, the other 30 columns are reserve for now. 
I chose the ARRAY for this project thinking of saving memory  and processing speed. 
I have a machine dedicated to this project, but still don't want to overload it, and it may be that in the future need to collect data for days.

Comment: But all help is welcome and I would like to hear a deep explanation of his ideas, I'm sure we can learn a lot from this.
Thank you.

Comment: Dear Joey, being honest, this is still a seed that needs careful not to become a crooked tree.
Because it is so precious to me your opinions.

Comment: I'm with 6 Laser Particle Counter (LPC) devices connected to a RS485/USB.
I get the data in intervals of 10 seconds and populating the Array with [310.120].
With the data that we receive we are populating the Array of cells, 
after entering all data let's make equations as the line below.
This line is excel and is just one sample:

array = ([32,6]-MIN([28,5]:[41,96]))/(MAX([28,5]:[41,96])-MIN([28,5]:[41,96]))
 
How to make this with this Array in C#?

Thank you.
ocaccy

Answer (score 1):

The comments you made below your question clarified it a bit, but the screwy nature of comments jumbled this line:

> ...receive a string like this  0#,22008,21930,00000, n / a, n / a !
>   But only use the 0#,22008,21930,00000. The...

So I'll just assume for now that those weird characters are an endline. Adapt it otherwise.

A set arraylength of 120 is completely unnecessary, and a 2-dimensional array adds no new methods usable here. We'll just use a jagged array instead. The length of 310 probably has some reason, so we'll keep that.

So on each row, the first 24 "cells" are the input from the stream. I'm unfamiliar with ports, but I can safely assume you can route that RS485/USB to a Stream object. 
Cells 0, 4, 8, 12, 16 and 20 are filled with IDs, one of {01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06} to indicate what LPC it came from.

But a bit later in the comments you specify wanting this:

> ([32,6]-MIN([28,5]:[41,96]))/(MAX([28,5]:[41,96])-MIN([28,5]:[41,96]))

Even in Excel, this would take the mini/max/average over those IDs as well. We're avoiding that in this code though, it ignores those columns.

```
class LaserArray
{
    private int minimum;
    private int maximum;
    private double average;
    private bool finishedReading;
    private StreamReader sr;

    public int Minimum
    { get { return finishedReading ? minimum : -1; } }
    public int Maximum
    { get { return finishedReading ? maximum : -1; } }
    public double Average
    { get { return finishedReading ? average : -1; } }
    public bool FinishedReading
    { get { return finishedReading; } }
    public bool StreamInitialized
    { get { return sr != null; } }

    private int[][] arr;

    public LaserArray()
    {
        arr = new int[310][];
        finishedReading = false;
    }

    public bool InitStream(Stream s)
    {
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(s);
            /*alternatively, as I have no clue about your Stream:
             * sr = new StreamReader(s, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
             * sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding encoding)
             * sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
             * sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int buffersize)
             * */
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Stream object.");
            sr = null;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void ReadInData()
    {
        if (sr == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initialize a Stream with UseStream first.");
            return;
        }
        if (finishedReading)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The stream is already read.");
            return;
        }

        minimum = int.MaxValue; maximum = 0;
        int currentTotal = 0;

        for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < 310; rowCounter++)
        {
            arr[rowCounter] = new int[24];
            int indexCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {                                   // 0#,22008,21930,00000, n / a, n / a !
                char[] buffer = new char[28];   //123456789012345678901234  5  67  8 makes 28 characters?
                try
                {
                    sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, 2 + 5 + 1); 
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    //some error occurred
                    Console.WriteLine("IOException: " + e.Message);
                }

                string input = new String(buffer);
                arr[rowCounter][indexCounter] = int.Parse(input.Substring(2, 2));
                indexCounter++;

                int currentNumber;

                currentNumber = int.Parse(input.Substring(6, 5));
                arr[rowCounter][indexCounter] = currentNumber;
                currentTotal += currentNumber;
                if (currentNumber > maximum)
                    maximum = currentNumber;
                if (currentNumber < minimum)
                    maximum = currentNumber;
                indexCounter++;

                currentNumber = int.Parse(input.Substring(12, 5));
                arr[rowCounter][indexCounter] = currentNumber;
                currentTotal += currentNumber;
                if (currentNumber > maximum)
                    maximum = currentNumber;
                if (currentNumber < minimum)
                    maximum = currentNumber;
                indexCounter++;

                currentNumber = int.Parse(input.Substring(18, 5));
                arr[rowCounter][indexCounter] = currentNumber;
                currentTotal += currentNumber;
                if (currentNumber > maximum)
                    maximum = currentNumber;
                if (currentNumber < minimum)
                    maximum = currentNumber;
                indexCounter++;
            }
        }

        average = currentTotal / (double) 310;
        //succesfully read in 310 lines of data
        finishedReading = true;
    }

    public int GetMax(int topRow, int leftColumn, int bottomRow, int rightColumn)
    {
        if (!finishedReading)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Use ReadInData first.");
            return -1;
        }

        int max = 0;

        for (int i = topRow; i <= bottomRow; i++)
            for (int j = leftColumn; j <= rightColumn; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == 4 || j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20 || j == 24)
                    continue;

                if (arr[i][j] > max)
                    max = arr[i][j];
            }

        return max;
    }
    public int GetMin(int topRow, int leftColumn, int bottomRow, int rightColumn)
    {
        if (!finishedReading)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Use ReadInData first.");
            return -1;
        }

        int min = 99999;

        for (int i = topRow; i <= bottomRow; i++)
            for (int j = leftColumn; j <= rightColumn; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == 4 || j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20 || j == 24)
                    continue;

                if (arr[i][j] < min)
                    min = arr[i][j];
            }

        return min;
    }
    public double GetAverage(int topRow, int leftColumn, int bottomRow, int rightColumn)
    {
        if (!finishedReading)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Use ReadInData first.");
            return -1;
        }

        int total = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = topRow; i <= bottomRow; i++)
            for (int j = leftColumn; j <= rightColumn; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == 4 || j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20 || j == 24)
                    continue;

                counter++;
                total += arr[i][j];
            }

        return total / (double) 310;
    }

}
```

This should be self-explanatory. Create a LaserArray, init the stream, readIn the data, and then have fun with the results.

Also, I'm bored and on vacation, so that's why I'm answering a year-old question in such great detail.

Also reputation.